# Avast keeps identifying MEGASync as virus

Tags: windows-8.1, anti-virus, avast, mega

I have avast installed on my computer for about 2-3 years now and had no problems. In fact I used to have a virus that only avast managed to remove and that's why I stayed with it. Also I had MEGASync Windows app on my computer for a year and half. Lately (about a month) avast keeps identifying the MEGASync app as a virus and blocks it from running. 
Two weeks ago I tried to redownload the MEGASync app and chrome recognized the installer as a virus aswell and I had to give extra permission for it to be downloaded (basically it blocked the file at the end of the download until I gave Chrome permission to keep it.) This has been fixed though (do not know if the fix came from a chrome update or a MEGASync installer update as chrome updates silently and I did not check MEGASync version numbers). But avast keeps recognizing the MEGASync application as a virus. Is there really something wrong with the application or should I just add the MEGASync folder in the scan exclusions list and get on with my life?

Comment: Check the file on [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com) for peace of mind. If it comes up clean, set it as an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to add it to the exclusions list. It may be false detection on the antivirus's part.

Comment: Without more information, it's speculative to make this assumption.  Answers should be definitive solutions.  Helpful suggestions should be comments.

Comment: " Is there really something wrong with the application or should I just add the MEGASync folder in the scan exclusions list and get on with my life?" That's what he asked. Unless you have a better answer to why it would recognize it as a virus.

Comment: I really believe it's a false positive aswell but, I would like some more info and more reasons on why this is happening...

Comment: It may think it is a false positive from being an application that copies your information as backup. Antiviruses only scan and detect code that is a potential use for viruses, it doesn't care what the application is doing with the code. Is that what you mean on more reasons?

Answer (score 0):

It's a temporary file for mega.nz.  Look in your MegaSync app to see what file it's trying to sync.  That filename is the actual problem and may actually have a virus.

The solution would be to delete that file from the Mega web site app.